# How to generate list of indexes not values with itertools.product()?

Tags: python

I have two lists how do I generate a list of index pairs.  Using `itertools.product(a_list, b_list)` I can create a list of value pairs, but cannot figure out how to do it for the indexes.

Here is a subset of the data and the required result.

```
a_list = [12970,12971,12972,...]
b_list = [1, 2,...]

result = [(0,0),(0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1),...]
```

Comment: you need to pass it the indices.

Comment: Generate the `product` of `range(len(a_list))` and `range(len(b_list))`

Comment: Also `a-list` and `b-list` are not valid Python identifiers.

Comment: itertools doesn't care what *you* think the arguments are; it cares only about the values.  If you want product of number ranges 0-n and 0-m, you have to pass it those sets of numbers.

Comment: Sounds like a probable [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me… What problem are you trying to solve with this list of index pairs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
itertools.product(range(len(a_list)), range(len(b_list)))
```

Comment: @blhsing Well, that's OP's fault.

Comment: Thanks @Miguel, this is a simple solution and works well for me.